# How do I get a scrollbar to work on tkinter with objects on a frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, scroll

I'm working on a GUI that requires a scrollbar because of a large number of elements.
The issue is after following many different tutorials, I'm still getting an issue where the scrollbar is disabled, and the supposed scrollable region does not fill the frame it's assigned (I did use sticky)

Any help would seriously be appreciated.

```
import tkinter as Tk

window = Tk.Tk()

#Right pane
rightPane = Tk.Frame(window, width=200, height=500, bg='white')
rightPane.grid_propagate(False)
rightPane.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
rightPane.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=(0,10), sticky='nswe')
scrollableCanvas = Tk.Canvas(rightPane, bg='white', highlightthickness=0)
scrollableCanvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')
scrollableFrame = Tk.Frame(scrollableCanvas)
scrollableFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
scrollableCanvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollableFrame, anchor='nw')
scrollableFrame.grid(sticky='we')

row=0
weightEntries=[]
for i in range(50):
    entryLabel = Tk.Label(scrollableFrame, bg='white', text='Weight {}:'.format(i))
    entryLabel.grid(row=row,sticky='w')
    row+=1
    newEntry = Tk.Entry(scrollableFrame)
    weightEntries.append(newEntry)
    newEntry.insert(0, 'test text')
    newEntry.grid(row=row,sticky='we',pady=(0,5))
    row+=1

scrollableCanvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollableFrame, anchor='nw')

vScrollbar = Tk.Scrollbar(rightPane, orient='vertical', command=scrollableCanvas.yview)
vScrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nswe')
scrollableCanvas.config(yscrollcommand = vScrollbar.set, scrollregion = scrollableCanvas.bbox('all'))


Tk.mainloop()
```

I'm very lost

Comment: You need to call `window.update()` before configure the `scrollregion`

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Why does it work?
Sidenote: Would you happen to have an idea as to why the frame doesn't stretch to fit the canvas width?

Comment: It is because when `scrollregion` is configured, the widgets are not actually layout by the layout manager yet as the tkinter mainloop does not take the control.  Calling `window.update()` lets the layout manager to process the layout of the widgets.